# Show keyboard for edittext when fragment starts

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

When my fragment starts, I want my edittext to be in focus/let user to just start typing in it.  I am able to get it in focus with requestFocus(), but I cannot get the keyboard to show up.

I have tried both this:

```
edit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.search);
edit.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager imgr = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imgr.showSoftInput(edit, 0);
```

and

```
edit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.search);
InputMethodManager imgr = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imgr.showSoftInput(edit, 0);
edit.requestFocus();
```

How can I get the keyboard to show up for EditText?

Comment: This is what worked for me - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759253/show-keyboard-automatically/39658629#39658629](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759253/show-keyboard-automatically/39658629#39658629)

Comment: My reputation is too low to comment the question. I answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43807917/5390932) with a method to control when to show or hide the keyboard

Comment: Check the recommended Answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60666198/6903609

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Does this work?

```
imgr.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

Comment: If you have trouble closing it use one other [these methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#hideSoftInputFromInputMethod%28android.os.IBinder,%20int%29)

Comment: This feels like a workaround. The correct procedure should be either as OP suggested or to call `imgr.showSoftInput(getView(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)`. Toggle will actually *close* the keyboard if it happens to already be open. The solution described is the only one I've gotten to work though, so is this a bug in the framework? Better solution or explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: @Nilzor I know your comment is a bit old, but recently had the same issue and found this bug report https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25812 .  May be related, haven't seen much from the Android team on it though, so not sure it has priority.

Comment: @Nilzor - I tried your code, for me it doesn't work when I open the fragment for the first time, but it works the second time. Any hint ? Thanks!

Comment: Confirming it works on Fragment.onCreateView every time the Fragment comes onto the screen. Thank you!

Answer (score 18):

You can try this

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    edit.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            edit.requestFocus();
            InputMethodManager imgr = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imgr.showSoftInput(edit, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This Solution worked with me although i didnt need to do the edit.post thing, i only added the 3 lines inside your run() to the resume method directly .

Answer (score 16):

Since using `showSoftInput` doesn't work for all cases and after trying some of the solutions mentioned here, like:

```
if (binding.account.requestFocus()) {
  requireActivity().getWindow()
      .setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
}
```

**I finally made it work using**:

```
if (binding.account.requestFocus()) {
  ((InputMethodManager) requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).toggleSoftInput(
      InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,
      InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY
  );
}
```

Since:

```
 binding.account.requestFocus()
```

only request the focus for the `EditText` (it doesn't open the keyboard)

and

```
((InputMethodManager) requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).toggleSoftInput(
      InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,
      InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY
  );
```

is the only solution that appears to be working correctly to show the keyboard (and the most voted one)

Good luck! :-)

Comment: this works, it opens the keyboard, But how do I close the keyboard when dismissing my DialogFragment?

Comment: Right now I'm not able to give you an answer since the code is in another project. But I'm pretty sure you will find something in StackOverflow :-)

Answer (score 11):

I have helpful extension for that:

```
fun EditText.showKeyboard() {
    if (requestFocus()) {
        (getActivity()?.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager)
            .showSoftInput(this, SHOW_IMPLICIT)
        setSelection(text.length)
    }
}
```

You will also need this one:

```
fun View.getActivity(): AppCompatActivity?{
    var context = this.context
    while (context is ContextWrapper) {
        if (context is AppCompatActivity) {
            return context
        }
        context = context.baseContext
    }
    return null
}
```

Comment: oh love Kotlin ext! :)

Answer (score 5):

After trying all solutions here and on other questions related, Here's the method that works for me:

```
editText.postDelayed(Runnable { showKeyboard(activity, editText)} , 50)


fun showKeyboard(activity: Activity, editText: EditText) {
    val inputMethodManager = activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    editText.requestFocus()
    inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(this, 0)
}
```

The fun fact is when you call it without postDeleayed it won't work, even if you just delay it for 1 millisecond it still won't work :D

You can also use it as an extension like this:

```
fun EditText.showKeyboard(activity: Activity) {
    val inputMethodManager = activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    requestFocus()
    inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(this, 0)
}
```

if you don't like to pass activity as a parameter, you use this  extension function as @Rafols suggests:

```
fun View.getActivity(): AppCompatActivity? {
    var context = this.context
    while (context is ContextWrapper) {
        if (context is AppCompatActivity) {
            return context
        }
        context = context.baseContext
    }
    return null
}
```

then your method will look like this:

```
fun EditText.showKeyboard() {
    val inputMethodManager = getActivity()!!.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    requestFocus()
    inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(this, 0)
}
```

also if you have a text already in your EditText, its better set selection at the end of your existing text:

```
fun EditText.showKeyboard() {
    val inputMethodManager = getActivity()!!.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    requestFocus()
    inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(this, 0)
    setSelection(length())
}
```

and if you want to start it when fragment starts:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    editText.postDelayed(Runnable { editText.showKeyboard()} , 50)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    @Override
public void onHiddenChanged (boolean hidden)
{
    super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);

    if(hidden)
    {
        hideKeyboard(yourView);
    }
    else
    {
        toggleKeyboard(yourView);
    }
}

    public static void toggleKeyboard(View v)
{
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    v.requestFocus();

    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
}

public static void hideKeyboard(View v)
{
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

EditText.**requestFocus**() + InputMethodManager.**showSoftInput**() = Show IME for EditText

use EditText.**performAccessibilityAction**(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK, null) in Fragment.onViewCreated() instead

```
    void maybeShowInputMethod() {
        // use addOnPreDrawListener instead of addOnGlobalLayoutListener
        // because execute sequence: onGlobalLayout-> Restore focus -> onPreDraw
        getView().getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                getView().getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

                // always requestFocus when fragment enter or show
                getView().requestFocus();
                final View currentFocus = getView().findFocus();
                if ((currentFocus != null) && currentFocus.onCheckIsTextEditor()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "maybeShowInputMethod:: currentFocus=" + currentFocus);
                    currentFocus.performAccessibilityAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK, null);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

---

or create subclass of EditText and override **public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo editorInfo)**

```
public class ImeAwareEditText extends EditText {
private boolean mHasPendingShowSoftInputRequest;
final Runnable mRunShowSoftInputIfNecessary = () -> showSoftInputIfNecessary();

public ImeAwareEditText(Context context) {
    super(context, null);
}

public ImeAwareEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ImeAwareEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public ImeAwareEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr,
        int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}

/**
 * This method is called back by the system when the system is about to establish a connection
 * to the current input method.
 *
 * <p>This is a good and reliable signal to schedule a pending task to call
                                                                                                                                                                                                                     52,6          Top
 *
 * <p>This is a good and reliable signal to schedule a pending task to call
 * {@link InputMethodManager#showSoftInput(View, int)}.</p>
 *
 * @param editorInfo context about the text input field.
 * @return {@link InputConnection} to be passed to the input method.
 */
@Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo editorInfo) {
    final InputConnection ic = super.onCreateInputConnection(editorInfo);
    if (mHasPendingShowSoftInputRequest) {
        removeCallbacks(mRunShowSoftInputIfNecessary);
        post(mRunShowSoftInputIfNecessary);
    }
    return ic;
}

private void showSoftInputIfNecessary() {
    if (mHasPendingShowSoftInputRequest) {
        final InputMethodManager imm =
                getContext().getSystemService(InputMethodManager.class);
        imm.showSoftInput(this, 0);
        mHasPendingShowSoftInputRequest = false;
    }
}

public void scheduleShowSoftInput() {
    final InputMethodManager imm = getContext().getSystemService(InputMethodManager.class);
    if (imm.isActive(this)) {
        // This means that ImeAwareEditText is already connected to the IME.
        // InputMethodManager#showSoftInput() is guaranteed to pass client-side focus check.
        mHasPendingShowSoftInputRequest = false;
        removeCallbacks(mRunShowSoftInputIfNecessary);
        imm.showSoftInput(this, 0);
        return;
    }

    // Otherwise, InputMethodManager#showSoftInput() should be deferred after
    // onCreateInputConnection().
    mHasPendingShowSoftInputRequest = true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Kotlin**

To automatically show/hide the keyboard in fragment...

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    requireView().edit_text_ID.showKeyboard()

    requireView().edit_text_ID.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
     if (!hasFocus){
        hideKeyboardFrom(requireContext(), requireView())
     }
    }
}

fun EditText.showKeyboard() {
    if (requestFocus()) {
        (activity?.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager)
            .showSoftInput(this, SHOW_IMPLICIT)
        setSelection(text.length)
    }
}

fun hideKeyboardFrom(context: Context, view: View) {
    val imm =
        context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
}
```

A little piesce of info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17789187/7795072).

Answer (score 1):

Below delay code work for me

```
editTextLabel.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) activity
                            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    keyboard.showSoftInput(editTextLabel, 0);
                }
            }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are new SDKs for showing and hiding keyboards/system bars now: `WindowCompat.getInsetsController`

and the short reason behind the problem is this: You won't be able to show the keyboard while the lifecycle methods are still finishing.

Here is a useful extension function, using latest recommended SDKs for showing system components, with a `post { }` call to solve showing the keyboard during Fragment starting:

```
fun EditText.showKeyboard(activity: Activity) {
    requestFocus()
    post {
        WindowCompat.getInsetsController(activity.window, this).show(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())
    }
}
```

Then simply `yourEditText.showKeyboard(requireActivity())` will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Another way to make the keyboard open when your fragment starts is to call `requestFocus()` in `onCreateView` and react accordingly by opening the keyboard if and only if the `EditText` is focusable.

```
if(this.editText.requestFocus())
{
    getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, using adding 2 lines will work like a charm:

If using XML

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Else in Java:

```
view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
view.requestFocus();
```

Comment: Dear random visitor, please provide an explanation for the downvote. That would help me learn what was wrong in this solution because this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin

The keyboard opens when you start the fragment

```
    override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)

    activity?.window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);

    return fragmentView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

toogleSoftInput is now deprecated.
For kotlin

```
   private fun showKeyboard() {
    val imm: InputMethodManager =
        context?.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.showSoftInput(binding.yourEditText, 0)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As Nilzor said this works

```
imgr.showSoftInput(getView(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
```

and I agree it is a best solution than toogleSoftInput

Answer (score -1):

this article helped me

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_name, container);
  editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_yourName);
  editText.requestFocus();
  getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                       LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
   return view;
}
```

https://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/show-soft-keyboard-automatically-when-edittext-receives-focus/