# Show keyboard automatically

Tags: java, android, keyboard, focus, android-activity

Please explain me the issue about soft keyboard.
For example, I have an EditText on my activity or dialogfragment or fragmentactivity, whatever.
here it is:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edPswrd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

When it shows for the first time I do not see the soft keyboard and have to press editText for it to receive focus and the keyboard appears. Another activities are different, when it appears on screen the keyboard are loaded without any help.
I thought that

> < requestFocus />

means that EditText will be focused and keyboard will appear, but I am wrong.

How should I manage what component will receive focus and keyboard will **automatically** appear.

Comment: I find it is better to NOT check Focusable on the TextEdit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show soft-keyboard when edittext is focused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105354/how-to-show-soft-keyboard-when-edittext-is-focused)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I think it's a bug or a feature which tries to present the whole activity to you without obscuring it with the soft keyboard at first. I've searched once for information regarding that but unfortunately found nothing coming from a really reliable source.

Anyway, to show the soft keyboard you can do this:

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text_id);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

I've also seen this code that should force the soft keyboard to become visible just after activity start, but never tried it:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

And if you want to hide soft keyboard you can do this:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

**Edit:**

For a `DialogFragment` this should work: in the `onCreateView()` method do this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_id, container);
    EditText editText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_id);

    // show soft keyboard
    editText.requestFocus();
    getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: I tried, but not one of method here doesn't work with my dialogfragment. I did this: InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  imm.showSoftInput(edPswrd, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);  And it doesn't work :(

Comment: thank you. I imported android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams but still there is a error SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: I also did this: getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE); like in advise below but keyboard still doesn't appear

Comment: also I just tried you "hide keyboard" on other activity, wrote this InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0); in onCreate() but keyboard appears :(

Comment: I got it to work in onCreateDialog also. See [my response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759253/show-keyboard-automatically/29923690#29923690)

Comment: How do you get the keyboard to disappear after you dismiss the dialog? The keyboard stays up even after dismissing the dialog if you use `getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);`.

Answer (score 34):

Open the Android Manifest file.

Look for the activity tag like this

```
<activity  
        android:name="com.example.framework.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"       //Add this line    
         >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Add the line android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"  as shown above

Comment: ok, thank you, it worked for the activity, and it didn't suit for dialogs.

Comment: what about viewpager?!

Answer (score 19):

I know this has already been answered, but I found a way to do the accepted answer in `onCreateDialog` instead of just in `onCreateView`. When you finish with the builder, before you return do the following:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());  
// blah blah blah do builder stuff here like setTitle, setView, etc

Dialog d = builder.create();
```

Here's the important part:

```
d.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
return d;
```

Comment: I had to use SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE to show keyboard (Nexus 5). Anyway, thanks for the solution in onCreateView() method.

Comment: How do you dismiss the keyboard if you use this method of showing the keyboard?

Comment: same as always. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200281/programatically-hide-show-android-soft-keyboard) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Answer (score 11):

add to onCreate or onStart();

```
myView.requestFocus();
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

Comment: I have got a dialogfragment and did this: edPswrd.requestFocus();
  getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE); It doesn't work :(

Comment: which part, the focus on the dialogfrag or the keyboad comming up ?

Comment: there is still no keyboard on screen when dialog appears

Comment: It works like this: getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE); Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   final View v = getDialog().findViewById(R.id.edit_text_id);
   v.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        v.requestFocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imm != null) imm.showSoftInput(v, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
      }
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

for me by adding this line **android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"** in your manifest  like this

```
**<activity
            android:name=".mmmmm.zzzzzzz.yyyyyy.xxxxxx"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_print_recharge"></activity>**
```

this is how I solved it

Answer (score 1):

First I add `requestFocus` tag in my EditText

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/mobile_number_edit_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:hint="@string/give_mobile_number"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="11"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="@color/body"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_13ssp"
                    app:fontFamily="@font/hkgrotesk_regular"
                    >

                    <requestFocus />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText>
```

then I create an extension function to open Keyboard. Here it is

```
fun Activity.showKeyboard() {
    val imm = this.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager

    var view = this.currentFocus
    if (view == null) view = View(this)

    imm.showSoftInput(view, 0)
}
```

After that, call `showKeyboard()` in my Fragment

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


        activity?.showKeyboard()

        ... ... ... Your other code ... ... ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me -

Create your own EditText class and override following method -

```
public class FocussableEditText extends EditText {

    public FocussableEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public FocussableEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public FocussableEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasWindowFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasWindowFocus);
        if (hasWindowFocus) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.showSoftInput(this, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
        }
    }
}
```

http://debuggingisfun.blogspot.in/2014/08/android-show-soft-keyboard.html

Answer (score 0):

I Recommend the following link, i was followed the steps which is mentioned below link, perfectly working, it's pretty good answer, done in very simple steps. credit goes to answered person. hope it will helps the person who mess-up with keyboard popup on dialog activity.

[DialogFragment and force to show keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237952/dialogfragment-and-force-to-show-keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and it works nice...

You can use the

> Utilities.showSoftKeyboard(...)

anywhere across your code

```
public final class Utilities {

  // Shows the soft keyboard. V on which view (typically EditText) to focus the keyboard input
  public static void showSoftKeyboard(Activity activity, EditText editText) 
  {
      InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
      imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
  }
}

/**
 * Called when user clicks/touches the search button
 * @param v The clicked/touched view (EditText)
 */
protected void onSearchButtonClick(View v)
{
    EditText seekTopic = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SeekTopicBox);
    setActivityContent(seekTopic.getText().toString());
}
```

The

> onSearchButtonClick()

method belongs to the activity, which hold the EditView which I want to edit and therefore I need the soft keyboard..

HTH