# DialogFragment and force to show keyboard

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have a problem with my DialogFragment. So to create my view, I use the method described on the android blog.
Here is my DialogFragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View myLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_connect, null);

    edit = (EditText) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.password_edit);
    edit.requestFocus();
    getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);

    return myLayout;
}
```

If I use onCreateView(), it works but I would like create an AlterDialog and to do this, I have the following code :

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    builder
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    callback.onYesConnectClick(edit.getText().toString());
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.refuse, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    callback.onNoConnectClick();
                }
            });

    return builder.create();
}
```

If I comment the code from onCreateView(), the app works but I can't force the keyboard to be shown and if I uncomment onCreateView(), I get a crash.
Here is the stack trace :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test/com.test.ProfileActivity_}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException:     requestFeature() must be called before adding content
AndroidRuntime at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2312)
AndroidRuntime at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2362)
AndroidRuntime at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
AndroidRuntime at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1250)
AndroidRuntime at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
AndroidRuntime at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
AndroidRuntime at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5229)
AndroidRuntime at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
AndroidRuntime at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
AndroidRuntime at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
AndroidRuntime at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
AndroidRuntime at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
AndroidRuntime Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
```

So my question ==> Can I use the AlertDialog and show the keyboard when the dialog appears ?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

override `onActivityCreated` in your dialogfragment and put `getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);` in there

Comment: wtf ?! I looked for so much time and the solution was so easy ! Yet, there is one thing I don't understand. I tried to set android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" in the manifest about the activity which is responsible of starting the dialog and it doesn't work ...

Comment: Thank you!! There are about a dozen other 'solutions' to this problem on StackOverflow and none of them work for me... but this one does.

Comment: This seems the most working solutions among all I can find.  I am curious why this has to be called in onActivityCreated, instead of onResume()?  I really love to hear some explanations.

Comment: I tried so many things and this is the only thing that worked :O

Comment: I have a DialogFragment which a custom view inflating this library. https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView. I could not get the keyboard to show when the MaterialSearchView launches from my DialogFragment.

Comment: Use `WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE`. This solution works, but if you want to delay showing a keyboard, it won't work (for instance, `lifecycleScope.launch {
            delay(300)
            dialog?.window?.setSoftInputMode(SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE)
        }`.

Answer (score 21):

The answer of tyczj does not work for me.

The solution was, inside onCreateDialog

```
Dialog d = builder.create();
d.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
return d;
```

In the end, the code would be like this

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    builder
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    callback.onYesConnectClick(edit.getText().toString());
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.refuse, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    callback.onNoConnectClick();
                }
            });

    Dialog d = builder.create();
        d.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
return d;
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Use `"SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE"` instead of `"SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE"` either in `onActivityCreated` or `onCreateDialog` method.

Comment: This was the solution for me combined with Purgarcita solution in onCreateDialog at the end.

Comment: @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (getDialog() != null && getDialog().getWindow() != null)
            getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    }

This worked

Answer (score 8):

Watch out for the `setLayout()` call if you use it. It took me a while to realize that it may override your window's attributes. After wrapping it into a handler, the accepted solution worked for me.

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

    return dialog;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // without a handler, the window sizes itself correctly
    // but the keyboard does not show up
    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(DIALOG_WIDTH, DIALOG_HEIGHT);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: just perfect!. `setLayout()` was creating the problem

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show a keyboard after a short delay, you should use another method. Solutions with `onActivityCreated` and `onCreateDialog` work right, but for instant keyboard showing. If you have `EditText`, you should open the keyboard over it, not over a dialog. See pictures at https://stackoverflow.com/a/65007148/2914140.

```
fun showKeyboard(view: EditText) {
    val imm = view.context.getSystemService(
        Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager?
    imm?.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
}


override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)

    val view = activity?.layoutInflater?.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null)

    view?.edit_text?.run {
        requestFocus() // Required for showing a keyboard.
        setText("Some text")
        setSelection(text.length)
    }

    val dialogBuilder = MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireContext()).apply {
        setView(view)
        // Set message, buttons.
        setCancelable(false)
    }
    val dialog = dialogBuilder.create()

    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
        view?.edit_text?.let { showKeyboard(it) }
    }, 100)
//    Instead of Handler you can use coroutines:
//    lifecycleScope.launch {
//        delay(100)
//        view?.edit_text?.let { showKeyboard(it) }
//    }

    return dialog
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason nothing worked for me other than this along with `myEditText.requestFocus()` in `onCreateView`:

```
override fun onStart() {
    dialog?.window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE)
    super.onStart()
}
```