# How to make Android EditText expand vertically when full

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have this EditText

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:hint="@string/write_message"
    android:textColorHint="@color/primary_color"
    android:ems="10"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:inputType="textImeMultiLine"
    android:id="@+id/message_input"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/primary_color"/>
```

When the box is filled up with user inputted text, it scrolls to the right to make room for more text, I do not like this behavior, and would prefer it if the EditText box expanded upwards when it needs more room? Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, this actually involves two things:

1. Making the `EditText` accept multi-line input.
2. Having its height grow as more text lines are added.

Therefore, to achieve this, you need to set up:

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

(Be mindful of the [difference between `textMultiLine` and `textImeMultiLine`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType)).

The full XML snippet would be:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/write_message"
    android:textColorHint="@color/primary_color"
    android:ems="10"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
    android:id="@+id/message_input"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/primary_color"/>
```

Comment: The `imeOptions` will be ignored if `inputType` is `textMultiline`

Answer (score 2):

Use both flags: `textMultiLine` will wrap your input, and `textImeMultiLine` will provide a break-line key in your keyboard.

```
 <EditText
    ...
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textImeMultiLine|textMultiLine"
    ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have multiline text, but it showed one line and a keyboard:

[image]

Though I have already set `android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect|textMultiLine"`, it didn't help. Then I understood that when the keyboard appears in `DialogFragment`, it collapses the `EditText`. See [DialogFragment and force to show keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237952/dialogfragment-and-force-to-show-keyboard/17238023) to show keyboard when `DialogFragment` shows.

Then I added a short delay (100-300 ms) before showing the keyboard. Now I have:

[image]

In `AndroidManifest` I set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` for current activity.