# DialogFragment focus EditText on dialog open for API 28

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-9.0-pie

I want to focus the first `TextInputEditText` in layout and automatically  display the soft keyboard when dialog is shown

I'm targeting API level 28.

Layout:

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/d_add_edit_name_til"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutAppearance"
            >
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/d_add_edit_name_et"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="User email"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:focusable="true"
            >
                <requestFocus />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

`DialogFragment` code:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    return dialog;
}

....

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    int dialogWidth = Functions.convertDpToPixel(300,activity);
    int dialogHeight = Functions.convertDpToPixel(250,activity);

    new Handler().post(() -> {
        getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(dialogWidth, dialogHeight);
    });
}
```

The answers from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237952/dialogfragment-and-force-to-show-keyboard) helped me solve the issue for API < 28.

I know from [Android 9 changes documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#focus) that:

> Additionally, activities no longer implicitly assign initial focus in touch-mode. Instead, it is up to you to explicitly request initial focus, if desired.

One of the ways to explicitly request initial focus ([as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51949487/keyboard-doesnt-show-up-when-enter-to-activity-in-android-pie-api-28)) is by adding `<requestFocus />` tag inside `EditText`, but still no success for API level 28 + `DialogFragment`

*Note that `DialogFragment` is from andoridx library (`androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment`)

Anyone else having this issue?

**Edit:**
The only way I managed to make this work is by adding the following code to `onViewCreated`:

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
        nameEt.requestFocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(nameEt, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    },200);
```

I don't consider this to be a valid answer as using threads in this manner makes the code unpredictable. Still waiting for a good answer

Comment: Try [This code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5106399/4168607) inside `onShowListener`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `OnGlobalLayoutListener` instead of `Handler`:

```
nameEt.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener{
            override fun onGlobalLayout() {
                nameEt.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)
                nameEt.requestFocus()
            }
        })
```

In such case you don't need additional explicit call  `dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(..)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText yourEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextInputEditText textInputEditText= (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.d_add_edit_name_et);
textInputEditText.requestFocus();
```

Comment: Any explanation (text) would be apreciated.