# Custom Dialog - Soft Keyboard won't open

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

**Custom Dialog Soft Keyboard won't open.**
How can I solve?
I've tried almost every method using

First use `InputMethodManager` to open keyboard, won't work,
Second use `InputMethodManager` and use `AlertEditText1.requestFocus();` also won't work.
Third use `dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);` , it *OPENS* keyboard, but won't typed to AlertEditText

Code did I use:

```
LayoutInflater inflaterload = getLayoutInflater();

View convertView1 = (View) inflaterload.inflate(R.layout.createpack, null);
final AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ListpackActivity.this).create();dialog.setView(convertView1);

dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
dialog.show();
```

Is there an another solution to work? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29923690/2590478) ?

Comment: Are you testing in **Emulator** or **Real Device** ?

Comment: @JayRathodRJ Real device, Android nougat Samsung J5 2017

Comment: @MidasLefko Yes, I saw this before I asking. I even tried those methods.