# How to open keyboard in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, keyboard

How can I open the keyboard when a fragment starts? I have already tried this code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout,container,false);
    TextView TVLarghezza = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.larghezza);
    TVLarghezza.requestFocus();
    InputMethodManager imgr = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imgr.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    return view;
}
```

But it doesn't work. I have to open the keyboard at startup.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58556751/6456129

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the problem is, that in onCreateView, the view is not on the screen yet.

Try this:

```
final TextView TVLarghezza = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.larghezza);
TVLarghezza.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TVLarghezza.requestFocus();
            InputMethodManager imgr = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imgr.showSoftInput(TVLarghezza, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

For showing keyboard use:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
```

For hiding keyboard use:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),0);
```

**UPDATED**
For Fragment:

```
imgr.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

Comment: I've already tryed this methods but they only work on activity, not in fragment

Comment: Somehow, HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY was the flag that made it work in my complicated fragment scenario. I don't understand if I read the docs about this flag, though.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, try to use `postDelayed`

```
    view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) mAppContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            keyboard.showSoftInput(view, 0);
        }
    }, 100);
```