# How to show soft keyboard perfectly in fragment in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I have an EditText inside a Fragment inside a Activity.

My Activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/login_bg">
    ...

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Activity config in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.demo.LoginActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/activityTheme" />
```

My code that use to start fragment in Activity:

```
private void startFragment(BaseFragment fragment, String tag) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tag);
    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

My Fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/common_background_color_white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/email_common_padding_horizontal"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/email_common_padding_horizontal">

    ...

    <com.example.widget.LineEditView
        android:id="@+id/login_email_input"
        style="@style/BaseEditText.LoginEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
    />

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

My Custom Widget `LineEditView` is a child class extend `RelativeLayout`,and it layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@color/common_text_color_black"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/common_cursor_background_orange"
        android:textSize="@dimen/email_fields_text_size"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/email_fields_text_padding_bottom"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/underline"
        android:layout_below="@id/edit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2px"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to show soft keyboard according to inputType property of EditText,and can  hide easily.

What I have tried but not work or not perfect:

1.According to [Show keyboard for edittext when fragment starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508363/show-keyboard-for-edittext-when-fragment-starts,i) can show soft keyboard but can not hide easily(even can not hide sometimes) and it show keyboard not according to inputType property of EditText.

2.I add following code to My Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container) {
    mEditText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit);
    mEditText.requestFocus();
    mEditText.setFocusable(true);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    mEditText.postDelayed(mShowSoftInputRunnable, 400);
    super.onResume();
}

private Runnable mShowSoftInputRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        FragmentActivity activity = getActivity();
        if (activity == null)
            return;

        InputMethodManager input = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        input.showSoftInput(mEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
};
```

but it can not show soft keyboard at all in my fragment.

I can not put EditText to Activity because it need to refactor a lot of code.

Does anyone have ideas to solve this problems?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here is the code I use which works very well in Fragments

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Context context) {
    try {
        ((Activity) context).getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        if ((((Activity) context).getCurrentFocus() != null) && (((Activity) context).getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken() != null)) {
            ((InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(((Activity) context).getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void showKeyboard(Context context) {
    ((InputMethodManager) (context).getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
}
```

Comment: Thank you,your answer help me a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This one works perfectly!! tried all other stuffs!! wasn't working as nicely!!

Comment: Your both more than welcome. This code is the best code I have used for showing or hiding the soft keyboard in android.

Answer (score 8):

> **hideSoftKeyboard**

In fragment need to call this when want to hide keyboard

```
hideSoftKeyboard(getActivity());
```

Call function

```
  private void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity)
{
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

> **showSoftKeyboard**

You call this for show keyboard in frament with pass the edittext

```
 EditText edittext=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext);
 showSoftKeyboard(edittext);
```

call this function

```
 public void showSoftKeyboard(View view) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)getActivity(). getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    view.requestFocus();
    inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(view, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help me.But your showSoftKeyboard Method may be need to execute in a view.postDelayed(),or it can not work.and your hideSOftKeyboard Method may be need to add ((Activity) context).getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

Comment: Thanks You! You save me!