# How to set focus to editText when fragment start?

Tags: android, android-edittext, setfocus

When `MyFgment` appear in screen, I want to set cursor focus on `EditText` in `MyFragment` automatically. I've tried `EditText.requestFocus()`, but it doesn't focus on `EditText`. How can I do??

Comment: Use Edittext edittext = view.findViewById(R.id.your_id); then if(!edittext.getfocus()) edittext.requestFocus()/ edittext.setFocus(true);

Answer (score 13, accepted):

editText.requestFocus() will put focus to your `View` if it is focusable . But I guess you want to show keyboard when it is focused. If I am right then the following code might work for you.

```
editText.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

The code is from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991522/how-can-i-set-the-focus-and-display-the-keyboard-on-my-edittext-programmatical).
You can also check [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFocus()) for details.

Comment: Neither requestFocus() not setFocusable working for me at all.

Answer (score 5):

set this in your xml

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

and you can set this on onViewCreated program `editText.isFocusableInTouchMode();
editText.setFocusable(true);`

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines from class,

```
EditText.isFocusableInTouchMode();
EditText.setFocusable(true); 
EditText.requestFocus();
```

or add these attributes in layout,

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this kotlin extension function

```
fun EditText.focus() {
    text?.let { setSelection(it.length) }
    postDelayed({
        requestFocus()
        val imm = context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.showSoftInput(this, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT)
    }, 200)
}
```

and call it on your EditText in `onViewCreated`.